# Should one write a line in a matrix when solving systems of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, systems-of-equations

Should one write a line in a matrix when solving systems of linear equations?

For example, consider the system consisting of $ax+by=c$ and $dx+ey=f$, should one write 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \end{array} \right) \quad \mathrm{or} \quad \left( \begin{array}{cc|c} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \end{array} \right)$$

Which one is perferred?

Comment: any of them help

Comment: @janmarqz What do you mean? I know it is a good and helpful method, but I ask what notation is perferred.

Comment: I would use the second, as there is no variable multiplied with $c$ and $f$, so it is make them different than the others. I don't think I have ever seen anyone use the first.

Comment: @wythagoras: The system can be considered as
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
-1
\end{array}\right)=\vec0
$$

Comment: Both of them are fine as long as *you* understand what it means. However, if you want others to understand what you mean, then the second one is more preferred. The line informs us that it's an *augmented* matrix. The first notation *may* confuse some people if the equations weren't provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments tell us that

- The second notation is generally preferred,
- The line informs that it is an augmented matrix.